# IIS Virtual Directory Get Pre Signed URL with Expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, amazon-s3, virtual-directory

in IIS, Is there a way to define some kind of a [filtering rule](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/filteringrules) to deny access to files within a virtual directory unless the requests are "pre signed" by some sort of an encrypted query string? Also is there a way to make the request expire? I can't find a way to have control over this.

What I'm looking for is very similar to what `Amazon S3 Amazon.S3.Model.GetPreSignedUrlRequest.Expires` property delivers, but in IIS. [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html) is a link to the Amazon S3 sample code.

Scenario of the desired goal:

Requesting: http://MyServerName/MyFolderThatIsAddedAsAVirtualDirectoryToDefaultWebsiteInIIS/MyImage.jpg
should always result in "Access Denied" by default. However, having a particular query string appended to the request URL should give access to the file. Also, I need the URL to expire after a certain period of time until a new valid query string is provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need some sort of HTTP Module here to deal with this as there is custom logic to implement for QueryString matching and expiration.

```
  public class HttpFilterModule : IHttpModule
  {
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += context_BeginRequest;
    }

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var qs = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["SomeKeyToCheck"];
        var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;

        if (MatchesUrl(url))
        {
            if (!IsAuthenticatedByQueryString(qs))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool IsAuthenticatedByQueryString(string qs)
    {
        //  implement code here to check qs value
        //  probably against a DB or cache of tokens
        return true;
    }

    private bool MatchesUrl(Uri url)
    {
        //  implement code here to match the URL, 
        //  probably against configuration
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks,
And to whom is interested: Here is a link that shows how to register the HTTP module in IIS:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms227673%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: New link for my previous comment as the previous link might expire: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673%28v=vs.100%29.aspx