# HTML5 Video Force Reload / Prevent Cache

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, html5-video

In the [HTML5 Video tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp), how can I force streaming the HTML5 video chunks on demand/load and prevent them from getting cached on the client side? In simpler words, how can I prevent the browser from caching the HTML5 video?

My ultimate goal is to make the video's source available for a short period of time (say 10 minutes) and then I will invalidate/expire the source. I know [how to invalidate a video HTTP URL in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679068/iis-virtual-directory-get-pre-signed-url-with-expiration) or whether to [do so if the video is hosted on Amazon S3 storage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html). However, if the browser caches my video, it will be on its own and the video would not be requested from the server anymore.

I've already checked out [this](http://ronallo.com/blog/html5-video-everything-i-needed-to-know/) detailed article about working with HTML5 videos with no much luck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see two decent options, and by using both you should have reasonable results:

1. Use unique urls by appending a timestamp:

   domain.com/video.mp4?t=" + new Date();

Or something to this effect. You can then check the value of t and reject if it's outside your window. By always requesting a new url because of the Date(), the browser will be forced to ask the server for the file.

2. Cache-control headers. Make sure you're setting them for for your video files in  htaccess to force a 10 minute refresh life span:

   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600"

   AddType video/webm .webm

60s x 10m = 600

Edit: Just saw the asp.net tag, set the cache control header in IIS.

Comment: That sounds promising, by the way the first approach will cover the second one because the browser will never be able to cache the video since source is always changing. I think that the second approach is useful just because it would save the browser the trouble of caching a "changing" source in the first place. Right?

Comment: Never trust the browser to behave as you'd expect. Best to hit it from both angles. If you choose just one, 2 is the easiest and quickest to implement.

Comment: Not brilliant but working solution. Maybe better to use a random number rather Date(), Add this javascript function " function getRndInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
} " to your scripts and then using that as: url + "?t=" + getRndInteger(1, 10000);