# Restrict access to content via a signed URL in IIS?

Tags: iis, asp-classic

In the past, I've used NGINX and the `ngx_http_secure_link_module` to achieve this, which has worked great. If you try to access a media file directly, you get a `403 access denied error`. But with a valid signed URL...

```
emample.com/media/audio.mp3?expires=[1 hour]&signature=[SHA2(filename+expiration+secret)]
```

...access is granted.

But I'm using IIS now, and I'm wanting to achieve the same thing. I've tried using ASP code with the URL rewrite module, where I'd create an empty media folder with an ASP page to process requests, store all media in an offline folder, and use the rewrite module to spoof URLs.

For example...

```
emample.com/media/audio.mp3?expires=[1 hour]&signature=[SHA2(filename+expiration+secret)]
```

...would rewrite to a page called "stream.asp". I'd check the signature, return an error if it was incorrect, but otherwise I'd change the content type property to match that of the file, then do a binary stream from the offline folder where the real file is stored.

This worked fine for documents, but for audio and video, it was sluggish, and you couldn't skip the content back and forth. I'm sure I could have adjusted the code to have made this possible, but accessing files this way put a lot of strain on IIS.

What I'm looking for is a simple URL check in IIS that either grants access to a file or denies it based on a URL signature check.

Does anybody know of an IIS module that can do this? Or perhaps it's even possible to use the URL Rewrite module to achieve this?

Comment: Does URL Authorization meet your needs? [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/understanding-iis-url-authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/understanding-iis-url-authorization).

Comment: @samwu That only works for users and groups on the server. It's a public website, and I'm using a MySQL backend to handle users with anonymous windows authentication. I managed to install Nginx on my Windows server with `ngx_http_secure_link_module` and access it through a subdomain. I tried documenting it, but honestly, it was just 3 hours of trial and error TBH. Unfortunately, I lost track.

Comment: Take a look at [this pseudo IIS Module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28769933/893670).

Comment: You can try open a support ticket for this: [https://support.microsoft.com](https://support.microsoft.com).

Comment: Sorry @Adam but my answer may be off in terms of what you want, what exactly do you mean by check the URL signature check?

Comment: Do you want to change the url (rewriting), or do want to execute some code after checking the url

Comment: There is no way to do it via classic ASP, you have to 1) Create an ISAPI handler or 2) Use Global.asax _BeginRequest method to intercept all requests and validate access there before allowing the request to execute further